# ImportError: No module named redis

Tags: python, ubuntu, redis, installation, package

I have installed redis using `sudo apt-get install redis-server` command but I am receiving this error when I run my Python program:
`ImportError: No module named redis`

Any idea what's going wrong or if I should install any other package as well? I am using Ubuntu 13.04 and I have Python 2.7.

Comment: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/redis

Answer (score 61, accepted):

To install redis-py, simply:

```
$ sudo pip install redis
```

or alternatively (you really should be using pip though):

```
$ sudo easy_install redis
```

or from source:

```
$ sudo python setup.py install
```

Getting Started

```
>>> import redis
>>> r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
>>> r.set('foo', 'bar')
True
>>> r.get('foo')
'bar'
```

Details:https://pypi.python.org/pypi/redis

Comment: I installed redis through pip, and it works fine with my console. But when I use crontab or jenkins to run it, the error again "ImportError: No module named redis"

Comment: You need to specify the path to the python you are using. @harperkoo

Comment: You shouldn't use sudo with pip

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same issue and this is how I resolved it. Check if you use a virtualenv named dev then don't do

```
sudo pip install redis
```

but just

```
pip install redis
```

This will install the redis package in your own virtualenv instead of your "complete" system, and this time your redis package will be found from your code.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, the error was that the default pip was 'pip3', and the redis package was installed under python3 packages.

This is not a redis specific issue, but if this is the case for you, try running:

```
sudo pip2 install redis
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and nothing helped until I realised that I had created a file "redis.py" so that `import redis` would import this file instead of the actual library...)

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed other answers are all but stating the obvious of doing a `pip` install or running the `setup.py` script from the source.  These are clearly helpful for some but there are other potential issues that might be preventing the `import redis` statement from running without error.

I've been bitten by this situation where my default *Python* version did not match up with the `pip` version and install path.

For example:

```
pip install redis
```

Will install `redis` but using the path to *Python3.11* and my interpreter (i.e. default path for *Python*) was using *Python3.09*.

You will in effect need to make the change from one end or the other.  Either by setting your default interpreter to `v3.11` or by using the `pip` install command for the correct default interpreter `v3.09` or whichever is in use.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I found that my Visual Studio Code was launching a different version than my command window.
When I did pip install redis, the command window found python in path differently than Visual Studio Code.

I needed to update my Visual Studio Code to reflect the updated python.

[How can I change the Python version in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48135624/how-can-i-change-the-python-version-in-visual-studio-code)