# ImportError: No module named redis and using geodis

Tags: python, import, redis

I am trying to use geodis from here : 
https://github.com/doat/geodis

I downloaded redis as explained in their website and here : [ImportError: No module named redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19288900/importerror-no-module-named-redis)

Now when I do the following as explained in the geodis website I get the error: no module named redis.

```
dn525f4i:src hmi$ ./geodis.py -l  40.90732,-74.07514
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./geodis.py", line 29, in <module>
    import redis
ImportError: No module named redis
```

But when I do the following

```
dn525f4i:src hmi$ python geodis.py  40.90732,-74.07514
Success!
```

I get the above "Success!" but it should idea be like following :

```
$ ./geodis.py -l  40.90732,-74.07514
Location: {'name': 'Rochelle Park', 'country': 'United States', 'lon': '-74.07514', 'zipcode': '', 'state': 'New Jersey', 'key': 'loc:rochelle park:united states:new jersey:', 'lat': '40.90732'}
```

Any idea on what I am doing wrong? 
Thanks!

Comment: hey dude, I know this is an old question and not sure if you ever got it to work, I discovered the version 2.0.9 is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type `./geodis.py`, you are executing the python called out in the first (shebang) line in `geodis.py`.

I suspect the python called in the `python geodis.py` call is different from the one in the shebang line.

Also when you do `python geodis.py ...`, you didn't specify the `-l` option - that might account for the different output.

Comment: It gives error too.
    dn525f4i:src hmi$ python geodis.py -1  40.90732,-74.07514
    Usage: 

    geodis.py [--import_geonames | --import_ip2location] --    file=FILE

    geodis.py: error: no such option: -1

Comment: Can you try geodis.py -l (letter l, not 1).