# Redis syntax help in bin/sh script?

Tags: redis

Currently i have plan a process of using a script to add key values into redis using rpush.

I am currently using bin/sh to launch redis.
But what is the syntax to rpush my keyvalue into redis server.

```
#!/bin/sh

redis-cli -h 172.16.114.54
rpush stlfile "fad.stl"         // how to rpush in with the correct syntax?
```

What kind of language is more suitable for redis so maybe i could change now to ease my future processes

Comment: Do you want to push the content of a file?

Comment: i just want to register a file name into redis called "fad.stl" 
but i do not know how to rpush using bin/sh

Comment: And what error do you get?

Comment: doesn't have any error, it straight went into redis-cli, did not rpush my value into stlfile too

Comment: Are you putting everything on the same line?

Comment: nope how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like using python would be easier to code Redis
from this post i found here i can easily install python.
[ImportError: No module named redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19288900/importerror-no-module-named-redis)

i managed to create a python script with this

```
import redis

r = redis.StrictRedis(host='172.16.114.54', port=6379, db=0)
r.lpush ('stlfile', 'variable.stl')
r.lrange ('stlfile', 0, -1)
```

when checked with another client i managed to see variable.stl went in :D