# How to I force MS Visual Code to use python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, visual-studio-code

I have been running Visual Studio code on the Mac for about 2 years now and I'm running into issues that I haven't seen before.  I have not personally run any updates for Code for quite a while.  lets say late November.

1)  A message at the lower right of my Work space that says

```
The macOS system install of Python is not recommended,
some functionality in the extension will be limited. 
Install another version of Python for the best
experience.
```

Unfortunately I can't update to Python 3.x and it shouldn't be up to Code to force me to update.  Is there a way to turn this message off?

2) Related to above is that some classes or language keywords (JSONUtils, @unittest, requests, def) are no longer being recognized.   Some constants that I have created and a variable defined to store a class.

```
sc = SomeClass()
```

This will be recognized at definition but later during usage it will not be recognized.

```
sc.SomeMethod( 1, 2, 3 )
```

sc won't be recognized.  None of this is making sense to me as it is not a pure pattern.  Everything is probably the same issue.  Need to point Code to python 2.7.

Comment: `I can't update to Python 3.x` why not? You could use `pyenv` :)

Comment: @grooveplex Company policy...  I just can't.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in VS Code.  A new future version will have an ignore button.

[VS Code Issue 4448](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/4448)

Answer (score 0):

*I still can't comment, so here it is an an answer instead...*

This looks like a duplicate of [How can I change python version in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48135624/how-can-i-change-python-version-in-visual-studio-code)

The short version that worked for me:

1. CTRL+SHIFT+P to open command palette
2. Choose "Python: Select Interpreter"
3. Point VS Code to the Python interpreter you wish to use.

Comment: Interesting... this did not fix anything.  I still get the MacOS system install message and my code is scattered with invalid/incorrect red squiggles.

Comment: @Keith Hmm perplexing. Did you try any of the tweaks in the linked post? I think we're beyond my depth now; the above worked great for me, but I'm on Windows and you're on MacOS so it's quite possible that Your Mileage May Vary.