# Python can't find installed module ('slackclient')

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, slack, slack-api

I am trying to build a slack bot for learning purpose but when I run the script get this error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'slackclient'`

I tried install and uninstall and then re-install with `python -m pip install slackclient`

```
import os
import time
import re
from slackclient import SlackClient

# instantiate Slack client
slack_client = SlackClient(os.environ.get('SLACK_BOT_TOKEN'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if slack_client.rtm_connect(with_team_state=False):
        print("Starter Bot connected and running!")
        #Read bot's user ID by calling Web API method 'auth.test'
        starterbot_id = slack_client.api_call("auth.test")["user_id"]
        while True:
            command, channel = parse_bot_commands(slackclient.rtm_read())
            if command:
                handle_command(command, channel)
            time.sleep(RTM_READ_DELAY)
    else:
        print("Connection failed. Exception traceback printed above.")


(STARTE~1) C:\Users\enest\Desktop\Slack Bot\starterbot>python starterbot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "starterbot.py", line 4, in <module>
    from slackclient import SlackClient
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'slackclient'

(STARTE~1) C:\Users\enest\Desktop\Slack Bot\starterbot>pip install slackclient
Requirement already satisfied: slackclient in c:\users\enest\desktop\slackb~1\starte~1\lib\site-packages (2.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: aiohttp>3.5.2 in c:\users\enest\desktop\slackb~1\starte~1\lib\site-packages (from slackclient) (3.5.4)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4.0,>=2.0 in c:\users\enest\desktop\slackb~1\starte~1\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp>3.5.2->slackclient) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: async-timeout<4.0,>=3.0 in c:\users\enest\desktop\slackb~1\starte~1\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp>3.5.2->slackclient) (3.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: multidict<5.0,>=4.0 in c:\users\enest\desktop\slackb~1\starte~1\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp>3.5.2->slackclient) (4.5.2)
Requirement already satisfied: yarl<2.0,>=1.0 in c:\users\enest\desktop\slackb~1\starte~1\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp>3.5.2->slackclient) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.3.0 in c:\users\enest\desktop\slackb~1\starte~1\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp>3.5.2->slackclient) (19.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: idna>=2.0 in c:\users\enest\desktop\slackb~1\starte~1\lib\site-packages (from yarl<2.0,>=1.0->aiohttp>3.5.2->slackclient) (2.8)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While the PyPI package is called *slackclient*, you import the module using the name slack:

```
import slack
```

Or, for example:

```
from slack import WebClient
```

Reference: https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient/wiki/Migrating-to-2.x

Comment: Thank you, I just realized the guide that I am following how to build the bot is using the 1.1.0 package.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error and found that the problem was my python settings in Visual Studio Code. I needed to change my python path from `"/usr/bin/python"` to `"/usr/local/bin/python3"` in the settings.json file. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48135624/how-can-i-change-python-version-in-visual-studio-code).

Not sure if that was the editor you were using, but essentially whenever I pressed the little play button at the top right corner of the editor, to run my python file in the Visual Studio Code terminal, it was running the command `python` instead of `python3` on the file.

Answer (score 0):

you can fix: Download C++ new version https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/  [image: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/]

Answer (score 0):

If your using python3 on your machine. You have to use `pip3` to fix `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'slack'`. And it works for me.

```
pip3 install slack
```

After successful installation we can use

```
import slack
```

or,

```
from slack import WebClient
```

Comment: `pip3 install slack` installs some very old package that is not maintained, `slack-sdk` or `slackclient` seem to be the better options.