# Python can't find installed module slackclient on MacOs. Any suggestions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, slack, slack-api

I'm developing a slackbot. After importing slackclient, I got `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'slackclient'`.

I tried all the options and followed suggestions showed in the post here- [Python can't find installed module ('slackclient')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57110933/python-cant-find-installed-module-slackclient). By those suggestions, I installed slack but got the following error while importing WebClient.

```sh
>>> from slack import WebClient 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'WebClient' from 'slack' (<path_to _venv>/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/slack/__init__.py)
```

I checked the slack version that seems like ok

```sh
slack         0.0.2
```

Any suggestions what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: It seems either you have not installed slackclient correct version. You can refer https://pypi.org/project/slackclient/#requirements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Using slackclient version 2**

```
$ pip install slackclient --upgrade
$ pip freeze
```

slackclient==2.1.0

> from slack import WebClient

**OR, Using slackclient version 1**

```
$ pip install slackclient==1.3.1
```

> from slackclient import SlackClient

Answer (score 2):

there seems to be a conflict between slack versions and imports. If you are using slack >= 0.0.2 and slackclient >= 0.36.2, try this instead:

from slack.web.client import WebClient

you can check that WebClient class is defined in that directory.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it to work by using

```py
from slack.web.client import WebClient
```

Answer (score 1):

The current version of slackclient for Python3 is 2.1.0.

To upgrade your environment run:

```
$ pip3 install slackclient --upgrade
```

You find the latest slackclient [here](https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient).

Comment: @pitt If this answer solved your question please consider marking it as solution by clicking on the checkmark next to the score. TY!