# ImportError: cannot import name 'WebClient'

Tags: python, api, webclient, slack

I can't do

```
from slack import WebClient
```

I get this error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'WebClient'

Have installed slack module

```
pip install slack
```

Error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "E:\Downloads\slack-automation-master\channel_messages.py", line 3, in 
>           from slack import WebClient
>       ImportError: cannot import name 'WebClient'

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57614585/python-cant-find-installed-module-slackclient-on-macos-any-suggestions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python can't find installed module slackclient on MacOs. Any suggestions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57614585/python-cant-find-installed-module-slackclient-on-macos-any-suggestions)

Comment: The PyPI package is called `slackclient`, not `slack`. So you install with: `pip3 install slackclient`

Comment: Do you have any file named slack.py or some other format. Just rename it. pip install slack > works fine.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`pip install slack`

`pip install slackclient`

Should do

Comment: `from slackclient import SlackClient`

Comment: @ajaykools I get this error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'slackclient'`. I have already installed `slackclient`

Comment: @HuLuViCa I hope you might have figured it out by now.

Answer (score 1):

uninstall slack and slackclient first:
pip uninstall slack
pip uninstall slackclient

then re-install, slack first

pip install slack
pip install slacklient

works for versions 0.0.2 and 2.9.3 respectively

Answer (score 0):

Move to pipenv.

```
pip install pipenv
pipenv install -r requirements.txt
pipenv run python my_program.py
```

Comment: Hi Pradeep, welcome to stackoverflow! You are replying to an old question and this does not seem to answer the question; using pipenv does not fix the import problem described.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error too after an upgrade of my dependencies where I was already having slack (0.0.2) and slackclient (2.9.3)

As I was in python 3.6, I upgraded to 3.8 just to check if then it works, and BINGO, it started to work (scumbag python)

Answer (score -2):

THere is no one solution. This is because Python version control and package dependency paths are a nightmare.
What solved for me was to
Sudo -H pip uninstall slack
Sudo -H pip install slack

In fact the install failed because it said that the dependency was already available.
Meaming, that earlier 2 versions of slack were installed. One in /usr/local/lib... folder and the other in /home/nitish/lib/...folder

What a spaghetti python is. Living up to it's name.