# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '...' even though module is installed

Tags: python, module, modulenotfounderror

Trying to import "libgen_api" module but get `"Module not found"` error.

`Pip install libgen-api` shows `"requirement already satisfied"` and the module exists in the python folder as well.

The documentation of the module says that it has to be called with `libgen_api`.

Other modules work fine. I am using VScode but the problem persists in the python terminal as well. I apologize if this question is redundant but so far I have not been able to find a solution anywhere.

Comment: how are you importing the library? is it like this : `from libgen_api import LibgenSearch`

Comment: your syntax is correct so must be an enviroment issue. have you checked where libgen_api is installed, from your terminal have you checked sys.path to see if it has the path where libgen ins installed?

Comment: @XXDIL yeah, I even copy-pasted the example code but the error persists

Comment: do your system have multiple python versions like Python 2.x and Python 3.x?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle the module is installed in /python39 but sys.path shows /python38-32. How should I fix this?

Comment: seems like you have more then one python version and installed the module in version B but running your terminal in version A. my first recomendation would be to used virtual enviroments like `venv` or `pipenv` as these make managing modules much easier for your projects

Comment: @DaveClosinger, does this answer your question about python path and vscode? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48135624/how-can-i-change-python-version-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: @collinsuz yep, that did it. Chose python39, which was the version under which the module was installed. Thanks a lot for the help, had no idea how to fix it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that VScode `sys.path` showed `python38-32` but the module was installed in `python39`. To fix the issue go to `View -> Command pallete -> select interpreter` and make sure to use the version under which pip installed the module.

This answered my question.
[How can I change python version in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48135624/how-can-i-change-python-version-in-visual-studio-code)