# How to change python version in VS code?

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code

have different version of python installed to my Mac, when I opened vs studio code it said I am using version 2.7.16 while the terminal for my Mac said its 3.8.5. How am I going to config that?

Comment: Uninstall 2.7.16. What happens?

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE that might be the system python 2 installation, in which case uninstalling it is a **very bad idea**

Comment: Got it. Then uninstall 3.8.5, what happens?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I change the Python version in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48135624/how-can-i-change-the-python-version-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Also likely to be a **bad idea**, as that may be the system *python 3* installation.

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE both python versions _could_ be system python required by the underlying OS, please refrain from recommending users to uninstall software, it could cause them harm.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. In the future, please use a descriptive title, like "How do I config VS Code to use a different version of Python?"