# How to pip install Google-API-Client in Virtual Studio Code?

Tags: python, google-api-client

Just recently got into programming and API's. I have a Chromebook and using a YouTube tutorial I downloaded Visual Studio Code and installed Python on it. On another tutorial on API's (specifically YouTube's), after setting up credentials it tells your to pip install google-client-api in a virtual environment. From my terminal in Visual Studio I tried $ pip install google-client-api and it gave me a syntax error code. I also tried it in my Linux terminal and it told me sudo: pip command not found. I actually managed to find the google-client-api in Pydroid and installed that, but I'd rather be able to run it in visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

Try using either

```
pip3 install google-client-api
```

or

```
python3 -m pip install google-client-api
```

---

The first command should work in most systems, the second should work in pretty much any system with Python3.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the info! Much appreciated. Before seeing this I did try sudo pip3 install google-api-python-client into my Linux terminal and it installed. Now that I've done that, it shouldn't it be able to run in IDLE or my Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Assuming you installed VScode in the same Linux environment, it should work. You may need to [change the python interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48135624/how-can-i-change-the-python-version-in-visual-studio-code) vscode is configured to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
python3 -m pip install google-api-python-client
```

(Windows 10 with python3 installed)
https://pypi.org/project/google-api-python-client/