# Syntax error in VS Code in python, while the same code is running well in pycharm

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

You can see the error in this image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBoyE.png

I am sure this is some kind of interpreter problem, but I couldn't find the solution. I am on mac environment.

Comment: Check to see the Python version in VSCode. Macbook often has Python2 installed, so VSCode might be using the wrong Python version. Hope these links help you: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment and https://stackoverflow.com/a/53699178/14426823.

Comment: I would assume that vscode uses the python version of your os (possibliy outdated). Pycharm uses it's build-in Envoirment. This might be a simple version discrepancy. Same idea as the person above me, and a little quicker as well....

Comment: which python interpreter are you using?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

maybe deploy it on a bash terminal and to deploy it write:
`python func.py`