# trying to make python3 defualt python version in visual studio code for mac instead of python 2.7

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

tried adding it to code preference settings json as an executable path and it still defaulted to python 2.7 instead of 3.9.7 like i wanted it to. anyone know how to fix this im running visual studio code 2020 for mac

here is the path i added to the settings json
"python.pythonpath": "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3"

Answer (score 0):

What does the lower-left corner say your interpreter is set to? If that doesn't point to the interpreter you are expecting then click on it and change it.

I think your problem is related to this issue with the python extension in this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48135624/how-can-i-change-the-python-version-in-visual-studio-code)

Updating visual studio code to the latest version might help.

Answer (score 0):

On the MacOs, you need to take `python3` instead of `python` to run the python3 interpreter. And of course, you can rename the `python` executable of the `python2` to something others such as `python2` to avoid the problem.