# Why is numpy not working in visual studio code?

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code, anaconda, jupyter

Today I installed NumPy with Conda. When doing that I created a new environment. After installing NumPy, I opened VS code and typed `import numpy as np`. It underlined "numpy" as an error. I hovered over the word "numpy" to see the error and basically said it doesn't know what NumPy is. However, NumPy works in the Jupyter notebook. I did a little research about this and from what I read, I have to somehow change the environment (or do something with the enviorment) I'm using in Visual Studio Code. **How do I do this?**

Comment: In the interest of content quality, duplicate questions aren't permitted. Please research your question before posting here in accordance with [ask]. This is a duplicate of [How can I change the Python version in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48135624/how-can-i-change-the-python-version-in-visual-studio-code)

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is not working is because you have not installed your library on your desktop. In order to use numpy on a desktop, you need to install the numpy library, whereas on Jupyter Notebooks, they have it preinstalled. So get pip on your computer, try this site https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-pip-in-macos/, and install numpy by using the command `pip3 install numpy` using command line on windows or terminal for mac.

Comment: Thank you! However I thought the whole point of Anaconda was to manage packages. Do you think it would be a good idea to install NumPy using pip or would it just become overwhelming with so many other packages in the future.

Comment: @ThatOneAmzingPanda, numpy isn't pre-installed with Jupyter by default.