# I have python 3.10 but my vscode shell say that i am in 2.7

Tags: python, shell, python-3.10

i just installed python 3.10 on my computer (with Ubuntu OS) but when i do the $ python --version commend of my vscode shell it says that i am in 2.7.17, is there a commend to change it to 3.10 ?

vs code clearly says that my code is running in 3.10 [as you can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bn24o.png) , i don't understand

Comment: possibly related [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48135624/how-can-i-change-the-python-version-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: i tried the solution, it change the interpreter for the code, but not for the terminal @YoshiMbele

Comment: Your PATH contains a directory which has an executable for Python 2.7. Do a `type -a python` before invoking `python` to learn more about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On ubuntu, `python` sometimes defaults to the `2.x` version, while you have to explicitly write `python3` to use the `3.x` version

Comment: @armand-marcelli may install the apt package `python-is-python3` to change the default symlink of the `python` command

Comment: how ? i mean, i want to run that commend : `pip install opencv-python`, where do i add "python3" ? @vultkayn

Comment: In that case, you would use `pip3 install opencv-python`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Python IDE like Pycharm so it would be easier to specify python version to use project by project

Comment: I really like vs code and i dont want to use any other version than 3.10, i just want to have a 3.10 teminal, why is this so difficult ?