# How do I change python versions on VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am following a python course in which the instructor is downloading extensions on vs code. After they add the python extension, there is something that pops up prompting him to download pylint. He says to first switch the version from python 2 to the latest version. For him, there is a button in the bottom left hand corner that shows the version, but for me there is no such button. Can someome help?

I tried looking up other ways to change the version but I couldn't find any. I was expecting for there to be a button to change versions.

Comment: Did you install the [official Python extension for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) and followed the [steps in the VS Code tutorials to configure your Python environments](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python#_environments)?

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of: [How can I change the Python version in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48135624/2745495)

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Answer (score -1):

Open the Command Palette, type `Python: Select Interpreter`

Then use the File Explorer to select a Python executable on your machine you want to use.

> He says to first switch the version from python 2 to the latest version

Python 2 shouldn't even be an option; it's end-of-life and wouldn't be installed on a modern system or fresh Python installation.

Answer (score -1):

It's on the bottom right corner for me [see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5VVp.png). If you click it it will show the option to select the python interpreter.

You can run this simple code to see which python env is being used

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

Comment: I figured out that all I had to do was to click "run and debug code" and for some reason the version switcher suddenly appeared. The code you provided didn't seem to show me any python version however it does not matter now since I fixed my problem, thanks!