# Failing to import `sentence_transformers` even though it is installed

Tags: python

This is the code I've been trying to run:

```py
try:
    from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer, util
    print("sentence_transformers is installed.")
except ImportError:
    print("sentence_transformers is not installed.")
```

Can anyone help me out as to why is this happening or what could I have been doing wrong? Even though I have it installed, it keeps giving me the same error every time I try using it.

I have tried uninstalling it and installing it again but it keeps throwing the same error over and over for some reason. When I run `pip show sentence_transformers` this is what I see:

```bash
# Output of the pip command should go here
```

Comment: Hello there, I've updated your question. Please try to copy and paste code in future, rather than just giving screenshots, though I know it's easier to prove the package is installed using a screenshot of that output.

Comment: Are you using the same interpreter in VSCode and your terminal?

Answer (score 0):

It could be because the package is installed in a different python env and you are using different python version to run. This mostly happens when you are using VS code for python.

eg: You might have installed it in python3.12 and using 3.10 to run or vice versa. You should create an env with a specific python version and use it to both install the library and run the script.  Here is a small example of how you could do it,

```
python3.10 -m venv name_of_the_env
```

then do, `source name_of_the_env/bin/activate`

https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

here is the guide to create an env.

once you do that, install package here,

```
pip install sentence-transformers
```

now to run this, you would either need to set the python to 3.10 or

do this, `python3.10 main.py` in your terminal or whatever you file name is.

Comment: I did the same but it has no effect, one thing i can see wrong is the package installed has a dash (sentence-transformers) however importing has an underscore(sentence_transformers) does that has anything to do with the problem?

Comment: you could try pip list, but generally it would show the packages for the main python version, so try doing, `python3.10 -m pip list` change the version that you are going to use. 

and to answer your question yes, What is happening is you are installing packages to a python version x, but your code is running on python version y. You can set python x as you default for running code as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48135624/how-can-i-change-the-python-version-in-visual-studio-code here, this should fix your issue. Hope it helps!